# jQuery hide() not working in enterprise mode emulating IE8. Read description

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

I have a menu div and a appbody div where appbody div opens a totally different application. The outer application is just html/js/jquery (along with java) but the other application that opens inside the appbody div has flex/flash/swf.

NOTE: Everything works fine until I run it with F12 Developer Tools With Emulation as Document Mode: Edge and Browser Profile: Enterprise. (Enterprise Mode emulating IE8, says the console).

```js
$("a.submenuTrigger").click(function(){
$(this).parent().find("ul.submenuHolder").show();
$("div#appbody").hide();
$(this).parent().hover(function(){}, function(){
  $(this).parent().find("ul.submenuHolder").hide();
$("div#appbody").show();
  });
});
```

On clicking menu, a submenu div is to be shown and the appbody to be hidden. In Enterprise mode, the appbody div isn't being hidden and the submenu div border is minutely visible as if its hidden behind the appbody div. Attaching the codes, thank you for bearing with the essay.

Also, note that the other app with flex doesn't have a doctype on its index.jsp page. Tried adding for HTML 5 as well as HTML 4.1 but the swf weirdly starts showing only half of it.

Comment: You are using hover function inside the click function.

Comment: Yes, Bhojendra. It is to hold the current state till the user hovers. After that there's a callback to hide back the submenu and show the appbody div back.